# Magento 2 Product Import Problem

Tags: magento2, import-products, visibility

I got an Error on Magento 2 Product Import - which says:

1. Value for 'visibility' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 1
2. Invalid value in Store column (store doesn't exist?) in row(s): 1

But in the Store column I has the value 0 and in the visibility, the value 4 for Catalog, search so I don't know why that's wrong ?!

Does any have an idea?

Comment: if any need to see the import csv -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/gftdjgtaaipru2k/abc-import-products.csv?dl=0

Comment: product sku might have a space in there

Comment: @FullSystem why sku value 1?

Comment: add one of the products from the backend manually and export it, analyze exported sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 product can't be imported if attribute set is absent in system.

You will receive next error after Data Validation:

Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set doesn't exist?) in row(s): x

You have to create attribute set manually in Admin Panel or via API request.

See: [Attribute Set REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#!/catalogAttributeSetManagementV1)

Comment: the Attribute Set "Default" in my import csv is also available in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the integer values, you need to use the text values, which are dependent on the locale.

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/289935/81745