# M2 Importer: Value for 'visibility' attribute contains incorrect value

Tags: magento2, import, visibility, cronjobs

If the importer runs with cronjob I get always the same errors on all lines:

> Value for 'visibility' attribute contains incorrect value, see
>   acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in line(s):...

If I run the importer manually it always runs without problems. But if it runs automatically with cronjob there are the errors.

I have tried everything. I have tried Integer values, I have tried English strings like "**Catalog, Search**" and also the same in German.

I have no idea what I can do. Magento version: 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3923

If the CSV data is in a different language(locale) than the locale of the default store view, the import will fail.

Best way to make sure is to output the valid options, by inserting

```
$this->_addMessages([print_r($possibleOptions, true)]);
```

in the `validateOption()` function of the file
`magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Validator.php`

You will need to use these exact options in the CSV, otherwise the import will fail

Answer (score 0):

"Catalog, Search" is correct value, if you still have issues - it can be one of the following reasons:

1. If you are import per store view ( as you say German?) check exactly value there and specify on the file
2. You import file is broken and can't be parsed , check quotes etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to provide the visibility value in store language.

For instance, if your store is in deutch, you can do something like

```
visibility = 'Katalog, Suche' // replacement of "Catalog, Search"

OR

visibility = 'Einzeln nicht sichtbar' // replacement of "Not Visible Individually"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in the end the problem was that I was adding without space after the comma "Catalog,Search". When I added "Catalog, Search" it worked.